# Flutter TextFormField Not Responding to Taps for Email Input hintText Not Showing

Tags: flutter, dart, gesturedetector, textformfield

I am developing a Flutter application with a login screen that includes both an email and a password `TextFormField`. While the password field works correctly, the hintText 'Email' is not displayed in the email input field, and the field is not responsive to taps — it does not gain focus or bring up the keyboard and  Strangely, setting the `isPasswordField` boolean to true makes the email field interactable and the hint text appears, which is not the behavior I want for an email input.

1. Ensuring that `obscureText` is set to `false` for the email field and `true` for the password field.

2. Using the Flutter Inspector to check for overlaying widgets that might be blocking the email field.

3. Commenting out `GestureDetector` widgets that could potentially intercept taps.

4. Testing on various emulators and a physical device to rule out platform-specific issues.

**Problematic Behavior:**

The email `TextFormField` is visible but does not respond to taps, making it impossible to enter text. This behavior persists unless I set `isPasswordField` to true, which is supposed to control the visibility toggle for the password field, not the email field.

**Code Snippets:**

*login_page.dart:*

```dart

```
import 'package:first_app/features/user_auth/presentation/pages/sign_up_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:first_app/features/user_auth/presentation/widgets/form_container_widget.dart';
import 'package:first_app/features/user_auth/presentation/pages/home_page.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    emailController.addListener(() {
      print('Email text: ${emailController.text}'); // For debugging purposes
    });
    passwordController.addListener(() {
      print('Password text: ${passwordController.text}');
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Dispose of the TextEditingController when the widget is removed
    emailController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true, // Ensures the keyboard doesn't overflow
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Login Page'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        // Ensures the content is scrollable and bounds are provided
        child: Center(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
              minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            ),
            child: IntrinsicHeight(
              // Constrains the Column's height
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    "Login",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 27, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  FormContainerWidget(
                    //TextField(
                    controller: emailController,
                    //decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Email',
                    isPasswordField: false,
                    inputType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  FormContainerWidget(
                    controller: passwordController,
                    hintText: 'Password',
                    isPasswordField: true,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 30),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => const HomePage()));
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      ),
                      child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          print(
                              'Login button pressed'); // For debugging purposes
                        },
                        child: const Text(
                          'Login',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // Add more widgets as needed
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      const Text('Don\'t have an account?'),
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => const SignUpPage()));
                          print(
                              'Sign Up button pressed'); // For debugging purposes
                        },
                        child: const Text(
                          'Sign Up',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.blue, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

*form_*container_*widget.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class FormContainerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  //properties
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final Key? fieldKey;
  final bool isPasswordField;
  final String hintText;
  final String? labelText;
  final String? helperText;
  final FormFieldSetter<String>? onSaved;
  final FormFieldValidator<String>? validator;
  final ValueChanged<String>? onFieldSubmitted;
  final TextInputType? inputType;

  const FormContainerWidget({
    //paramaters
    Key? key,
    required this.controller,
    this.isPasswordField = false,
    this.fieldKey,
    required this.hintText,
    this.labelText,
    this.helperText,
    this.onSaved,
    this.validator,
    this.onFieldSubmitted,
    this.inputType,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _FormContainerWidgetState createState() => _FormContainerWidgetState();
}

class _FormContainerWidgetState extends State<FormContainerWidget> {
  bool _obscureText = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Building FormContainerWidget'); // For debugging purposes
    print('Controller: ${widget.controller}');

    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8, // 80% of screen width
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(.35),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: const BoxConstraints(
          // Set a minimum and maximum height if needed
          minHeight: 40.0, // Example minimum height
          maxHeight: 50.0, // Example maximum height
        ),
        child: TextFormField(
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
          controller: widget.controller,
          keyboardType: widget.inputType,
          key: widget.fieldKey,
          obscureText: widget.isPasswordField == true ? _obscureText : false,
          onSaved: widget.onSaved,
          validator: widget.validator,
          onFieldSubmitted: widget.onFieldSubmitted,
          onChanged: (text) {
            // For debugging purposes
            print('Input text: $text');
          },
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(), // Add a border for testing purposes
            //border: InputBorder.none,
            filled: true,
            hintText: widget.hintText,
            hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
            suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  _obscureText = !_obscureText;
                });
              },
              child: widget.isPasswordField == true
                  ? Icon(
                      _obscureText ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility,
                      color: _obscureText == false ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                    )
                  : null,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `_FormContainerWidgetState`, you conditionally set the `GestureDetector`'s `Icon`. Instead, move that check to the `GestureDetector` itself:

```
            suffixIcon: widget.isPasswordField
                ? GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => setState(
                      () => _obscureText = !_obscureText,
                    ),
                    child: Icon(
                      _obscureText ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility,
                      color: _obscureText ? Colors.grey : Colors.blue,
                    ),
                  )
                : null,
```

Comment: Thank you, that's done the trick. I appreciate the help!